# using lvh me with laravel doesn't work

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel app installed on my linux locale machine, I would like to use lvh.me instead of localhost but when I do `lvh.me:8000` it doesn't work (Unable to connect), if I do only `lvh.me` it show me the apache page. What's wrong with the 8000 port ? how I can get it to work ?

Comment: I think apache only responds to :80 and :8080 port, though not sure

Comment: This depends entirely on what server you're using.

Comment: @naneri with localhost:8000 the app works but when I do lvh.me:8000 it doesn't!

Comment: @JoelHinz I am using apache, with localhost:8000 the app works but when I do lvh.me:8000 it doesn't

Comment: Go into the vhost (probably /etc/apache2/sites-available/lvh.me.conf or something) and set it to listen to 8000 then. :)

Comment: @JoelHinz there is no lvh.me.conf ! but only 000-default.conf :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for any one looking for the solution, I was be able to do it by start the server like the following :

```
php artisan serve --host=lvh.me --port=8001
```

instead of

```
php artisan serve
```

and it worked!

thanks to : http://laravel.io/forum/09-05-2014-php-artisan-serve-on-another-adress?page=1

hope this help someone in the future!